# Opening and reading a file in C

Tags: c

I have to write an app on C that opens a file, reads what is inside of it, stores that information on a struct and prints all the information. I did it creating `"empleados.txt"` and placing it on the folder where is `main.c`. This is the content of the `.txt`:

```
Juan
Perez
Rodriguez
11111111A
1200
Pepa
Bueno
Ruibal
22222222B
2300
```

It is not printing anything, and I don't know why.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct Empleado {
    char nombre[15];
    char apellido_uno[30];
    char apellido_dos[30];
    char DNI[9];
    unsigned int sueldo;
};

int main() {
    int i=0, j;
    struct Empleado num[50];
    FILE *idf;
    idf=fopen("empleados.txt", "rt");
    if (idf==NULL){
        printf("Error abriendo fichero ...");
        exit(1);
    }
    else {
        do{
            fgets(idf,"%s",&num[i].nombre);
            fgets(idf,"%s",&num[i].apellido_uno);
            fgets(idf,"%s",&num[i].apellido_dos);
            fgets(idf,"%s",&num[i].DNI);
            fgets(idf,"%d",&num[i].sueldo);                
            i++;
        }while(feof(idf)==0);
    }
    fclose (idf);

    for(j=0;j<i;j++){
        printf("Nombre: %s",num[i].nombre);
        printf("Nombre: %s",num[i].apellido_uno);
        printf("Nombre: %s",num[i].apellido_dos);
        printf("Nombre: %s",num[i].DNI);
        printf("Nombre: %o",num[i].sueldo);        
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: filemode of fopen is `rt` ?

Comment: Sorry for the question but just in order to be sure. What do you mean by printing? You do not mean by printing a hard copy, right?

Comment: Your compiler should be throwing some errors. You are directly converting a pointer to the file into a pointer to a char.

Comment: Dont't use `&num[i].nombre` to pass the char array buffer to `fgets`. Use `num[i].nombre` instead as it decays to a pointer to the buffer. You're actually passing a pointer to a pointer.

Comment: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_fgets.htm

Comment: `fscanf` instead of `fgets`, and `char DNI[9];` --> `char DNI[10];`

Comment: @BLUEPIXY Already did it. Im getting this `Nombre: Nombre: Nombre: Nombre: Nombre: 0Nombre: Nombre: Nombre: Nombre: Nombre: 0`

Comment: @PattySelman use `j` for index. also `while(feof(idf)==0);` is wrong.

Comment: @BLUEPIXY why if i use char DNI[9] I get this � thing on the compilation. Why I have to use DNI[10]

Comment: @PattySelman: the longest string in your example data has 9 characters. C strings require a 0 terminator. So your buffer needs to be at least of size 9+1 = 10.

Comment: @PaulR It isn't `[0],[1],[2],[3],[4],[5],[6],[7],[8]` there are already 9 characters.

Comment: @PattySelman: consider one of your input strings, e,g "11111111A". This has 9 characters. To store it as a C string it also needs a 0 terminator. So you need 10 characters, indexed from 0 to 9: `DNI[0] = '1'`, `DNI[8] = 'A'`, `DNI[9] = '\0'`,

Comment: @PaulR But DNI it only refers to `11111111A` and `22222222B`, that have 9 characters

Comment: Sorry - I used a bad example - "11111111A" has 9 characters, **and you also need a 0 terminator**, so you need 9+1 = 10 characters. See updated comment above.

Comment: `%s` of `scanf` family add a `'\0'` after the reading of the character(non-white-space). So this case of the nine characters it will overflow. it need 10-character area.

Comment: `[9]` in Array Declaration means the nine elements.

Comment: @BLUEPIXY @PaulR And if I want to compare that string with another one, I tried to use strcmp (`<string.h>`) but it gives a `value equal to 171`, instead of `0`.

Comment: [TEST CODE](http://ideone.com/o39XT0)

Comment: @BLUEPIXY I'm so sorry man, but I'm not getting the thing I want if I write `11111111A`. I copy my code into ideone.com. https://ideone.com/GyDaSA

Comment: `char NIF[8];... scanf("%9s",&NIF[10]);` --> `char NIF[10];... scanf("%9s", NIF);`

Comment: @BLUEPIXY It's working, but why I don't have to put `&` neither `[10]`

Comment: It should be a `&NIF[0]`. `&NIF[10]` point to after the area(next `NIF[9]`, `NIF[10]` is out-of-bounds.)

Comment: @BLUEPIXY but why my code doesn't work if I put without `%9s`. Is out of bounds to write a 9 character string and have `&NIF[10]`?

Comment: To me I can not understand what you did.

Comment: [SAMPLE for your help](http://ideone.com/M8k3Ad)

Comment: @BLUEPIXY With integers this doesn't happen? http://ideone.com/OZw7m0

Comment: index is beyond the range of the array. when `int DNI[10];`, DNI has 10 elements. DNI[0]...DNI[9]. Access was to the part that exceeds the range of the array is undefined behavior. It is rewriting an unintended area.

Comment: @BLUEPIXY Finally underestood it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`fgets`](http://www.openbsd.org/cgi-bin/man.cgi/OpenBSD-current/man3/fgets.3?query=fgets) wants the file as last argument and the target string as first.

The second argument should be the size of the target buffer, not a format string.

It seems you are confusing `fgets` and `fscanf`.

Here is an improved version (incorporating also the index fix from BLUEPIXY):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct Empleado {
    char nombre[15];
    char apellido_uno[30];
    char apellido_dos[30];
    char DNI[9];
    unsigned int sueldo;
};

int main() {
    int i=0, j;
    struct Empleado num[50];
    FILE *idf;
    idf=fopen("empleados.txt", "rt");
    if (idf==NULL){
        printf("Error abriendo fichero ...");
        exit(1);
    }
    else {
        do{
            fgets(&num[i].nombre, sizeof num[i].nombre, idf);
            fgets(&num[i].apellido_uno, sizeof num[i].apellido_uno, idf);
            fgets(&num[i].apellido_dos, sizeof num[i].apellido_dos, idf);
            fgets(&num[i].DNI, sizeof num[i].DNI, idf);
            fscanf(idf, "%u", &num[i].sueldo);
            i++;
        }while(feof(idf)==0);
    }
    fclose (idf);

    for(j=0;j<i;j++){
        printf("Nombre: %s\n",num[j].nombre);
        printf("Nombre: %s\n",num[j].apellido_uno);
        printf("Nombre: %s\n",num[j].apellido_dos);
        printf("Nombre: %s\n",num[j].DNI);
        printf("Nombre: %o\n",num[j].sueldo);        
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I think those `fgets` calls are probably meant to be `fscanf`, given the parameters and the use of a format string.

Comment: @Paul R: Probably, yes. But in fact, fgets is the better choice here, isn't it?

Comment: @PaulR If I use `fscanf` I get this: `Nombre: Nombre: Nombre: Nombre: Nombre: 0Nombre: Nombre: Nombre: Nombre: Nombre: 0`

Comment: And if you use `fgets` it shouldn't even compile because you are giving it invalid arguments.

Comment: @BLUEPIXY that's the thing man. You are awesome. Didn't see that.

Answer (score 1):

Change `fgets` to `fscanf` and remove `&` from the arguments of in `do-while` loop. `num[i].nombre` is converted to a pointer to `char` and similarly other members except the last member `sueldo`.

```
    fscanf(idf,"%s",num[i].nombre);
    fscanf(idf,"%s",num[i].apellido_uno);
    fscanf(idf,"%s",num[i].apellido_dos);
    fscanf(idf,"%s",num[i].DNI);
    fscanf(idf,"%d",&num[i].sueldo);
    i++;
```

Comment: It's not even `fscanf` in the code, though it should be.

Comment: Also passing format strings to `fgets` is an interesting, but not altogether helpful idea.

Comment: @Kevin Still giving some errors: passing argument of 'fgets' from incompatible pointer type

Comment: I'm saying you should replace `fgets` with `fscanf` in your code, as you are using it as if it's `fscanf`.

Comment: @Keving Getting this: `Nombre: Nombre: Nombre: Nombre: Nombre: 0Nombre: Nombre: Nombre: Nombre: Nombre: 0`

Comment: @PattySelman: you have a *lot* of mistakes in your code - you'll need to fix all of them before you program works properly - fix all the mistakes that people have pointed out already and then go through your code carefully to see if there are any further problems.